# how is CHAR type stored if BLANK_TRIMMING parameter is set TRUE? (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I wonder how is CHAR type column data stored if the initialization parameter 'BLACK_TRIMMING' is set TRUE.

Is it right that all blanks are trimmed and stored up to the last non-blank character?
ex)

```
-- BLANK_TRIMMING is set TRUE
create table t(c1 char(20));

insert into t values('Hello');
insert into t values('World   ');
insert into t values('Hello World   ');
```

in this example, I created a table with CHAR(10) type column and inserted 2 data.
I want to know how those 2 data are stored.

'Hello'
'World'
'Hello World'

Are data stored like this?

Comment: I've not tried it but most likely, no. The docs say *Allows the data assignment of a source character string or variable to a destination character column or variable even though the source length is longer than the destination length.* That doesn't sound like it trims spaces unless it is necessary to get under the target size limit. Unfortunately Oracle chose to make it non-session modifiable so it'd require an instance bounce to test.

Comment: The `CHAR` data type *always* stores the full number of bytes associated with the column, regardless of the size of the string you put in it. In general, and especially if you want storage allocated only for actual data, you should always use `VARCHAR2`.

Comment: You'd better take a look to the [BLANK_TRIMMING](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/BLANK_TRIMMING.html#GUID-9867835F-8AB6-4678-BE3F-9E4E27939BA9) parameter specification, which has nothing to do with trimming blanks at the end of a value, but with allowing values larger than the destination column.

Answer (score 1):

For questions like this, refer to the [Oracle `BLANK_TRIMMING` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/BLANK_TRIMMING.html#GUID-9867835F-8AB6-4678-BE3F-9E4E27939BA9):

> #### 1.35 BLANK_TRIMMING
>
> `BLANK_TRIMMING` specifies the data assignment semantics of character datatypes.
>
> ##### Values
>
> - `TRUE`
>
>   Allows the data assignment of a source character string or variable to a destination character column or variable even though the source length is longer than the destination length. In this case, however, the additional length over the destination length must be all blanks, else an exception condition is raised. This value complies with the semantics of SQL-92 Transitional Level and above.
> - `FALSE`
>
>   Disallows the data assignment if the source length is longer than the destination length and reverts to SQL92 Entry Level semantics.

So this parameter enables you to insert values into a column that exceed the column's length if, and only if, the characters that exceed the column's length are all blanks.

> Is it right that all blanks are trimmed and stored up to the last non-blank character?

**NO**, if you have a `CHAR(20)` column, it will still store all 20 bytes (or characters) and will pad shorter values so that they have 20 bytes.

What is does do is enable all these queries to work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name(column_name CHAR(12));

INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('Hello');
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('Hello World!');
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('Hello World!          ');
```

The first will be padded to `Hello`       , the second and third will both store `Hello World!` as the second exactly fills the column and the third will have the blank characters trimmed from the right of the string and the non-blank characters fit into the column.